# Lining up Divs, while using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a flash header like element in JQuery, that has three images that fade to other images.  I have each group of images in a div, but the divs line up vertically down the page, I want them to line up horizontally in a row.

Currently my css code is:

```
div#demos{
  width:940px;
  border:0;
}

.s1{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  background-color:#000000;
  width:225px;
  margin:0;
}

.s2{
  float:right;
  display:inline;
  background-color:#000000;
  width:225px;
  margin:0;
}

.s3{
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  background-color:#000000;
  width:225px;
  margin:0;
}
```

and my markup is:

```
<div id="demos">

    <div id="s1" class="pics">
        <img src="Image1.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image2.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image3.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>


    <div id="s2" class="pics">
        <img src="Image4.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image5.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image6.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>

    <div id="s3" class="pics">
        <img src="Image7.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image8.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="Image9.jpeg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change .s1 .s2 .s3 to #s1 #s2 #s3 because # represents an 'id' and that is what s1, s2 and s3 are

see example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NW4Ry/

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using the element ids `s1`, `s2` and `s3` in your HTML. However, you are defining CSS for the **classes** `s1`, `s2` and `s3`.

Either:

1. Define CSS in aggregate using the class `pics`
2. Or change the CSS to use id selectors, eg. `#s1`, `#s2`